# Get data from an http url Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to make an Angular app where it displays all the public repositories of Google's GitHub (https://github.com/google) and i manage to display a part of it by using the angular-in-memory-web-api:

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService{
  createDb() {
    const repos = [
      { id: 143044068, name: '0x0g-2018-badge' },
   ...
      { id: 88582010, name: 'address-geocoder-js' },
    ];
    return {repos};
  }
  genId(repos: Repo[]): number {
    return repos.length > 0 ? Math.max(...repos.map(repo => repo.id)) + 1 : 11;
  }
}
```

i used the GitHub API to get the repositories of the first page.

I wanted to know if there is a way to get all the repositories by using the link (https://api.github.com/users/google/repos?page=1 for my case) instead of typing by hand the entire database in my function createDb() ?

Comment: what data do you need (just the id and name)? Do you just need the snapshot in time data or do you need script e.g. python script for this to repeatably do this?

Comment: @AndrewAllen i only need the id and name and the snapshot in time data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text()` method to grab the content of that page, then parse it to array of objects and use forEach loop to take properties you need:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getReposFromURL();
  }

  async getReposFromURL() {
    let url = 'https://api.github.com/users/google/repos?page=1';
    let repos = [];
    const htmlContent = await (await fetch(url)).text();
    let parsedHtml = JSON.parse(htmlContent);
    parsedHtml.forEach((repo) => {
      repos.push({ id: repo.id, name: repo.name });
    });
    console.log(repos);
  }
```